# VideoView is not playing video in android Q but works fine in lower android versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview, android-video-player

I'm working on video player. Video view is not playing video in android Q, it shows can't play this video but in other lower android versions videoview works fine. Path of video is in internal storage of phone. Anybody knows about this issue?

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Let us know if you are getting any error message

Comment: I'm not getting any error nor activity or app is crashing. just videoview shows "can't play this video"

Comment: i found solution myself. By adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest inside of application tag then videoview works fine and also glide lib works fine in android Q if its not working

Comment: Cool ...Write it as answer and accept it.... may be in future it will help some other people ...

Comment: how to accept it. I'm new and i dont know much about stackoverflow

Comment: No you have to write answer there is a window below question Your Answer write answer there and post it and then just click right mark beside the answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution myself. By adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest inside of application tag then videoview works fine and also glide lib works fine in android Q if its not working